# Dice Class, a game of Cho-Han Bakuchi.. Java ( BAD OPERAND TYPES FOR BINARY OPERATOR '+')

Tags: java, string, int, args

I'm trying to simulate the game of Cho han bakuhi in my java program in which i create a dice class at first, then later in my main method i created two dice d1 and d2. I roll them both get randomized values from 1-6 . Here comes the problem when i try to add them. When i try to add the values of d1 and d2 into sum, i'm getting a compilation error , which is :
BAD OPERAND TYPES FOR BINARY OPERATOR '+'.. here is the code i wrote so far :

```
   import java.util.Scanner;


  class Die
  {

  private final int MAX = 6;  

   private int faceValue; 


   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }


   public Die(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   public void setFaceValue (int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }


   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }


       public String toString() 
      { 
             String result = Integer.toString(faceValue); 
             return result; 
        } 

}

public class Dice{

  public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Die d1, d2;
      int sum;
      String Cho;
      String Han;


      d1 = new Die();
      d2 = new Die();
      sum = d1+d2;
      System.out.println("This is the game of Cho-Han Bakuchi, select either Cho (even) or Han(odd)");
       System.out.println("Enter Cho or Han : ");

      d1.roll();
      d2.roll();
      System.out.println ("Die One: " + d1 + ", Die Two: " + d2);
    if((sum)%2 == 0)
    System.out.println ("Sum is Cho");
   else
System.out.println("Sum is Han");


}
}
```

Comment: Java has no operator overloading. The + operator can only be applied to Strings and numeric types.

Comment: On a different note, the `sum` is always computed before "rolling" your dice. It will always be `2` in your case.

Comment: @manouti maybe the game is rigged ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
sum = d1+d2;
```

it isn't sure what exactly to add. Since your `Die` class has a method for getting it's value, use that instead.

```
sum = d1.getFaceValue() + d2.getFaceValue();
```

Those methods return ints which can then be added.

Also, as taken from `manouti`'s comment, the sum you are using in your game is going to always be 2 since you calculate it, then roll, then use the sum from the first part. You should calculate the sum immediately after rolling the dice.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eran mentioned, in java you can only use `+` applied to numeric types or when one of the operands is `String` (the other will be converted to `String` by calling classe's `toString()`)

What you probably wanted to do is to sum the faceValues of both dices.

So instead of

```
 sum = d1 + d2;
```

use

```
 sum = d1.getFaceValue() + d2.getFaceValue() ;
```